# How to generate synthetic dataset with dependent and independent features?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, data-mining

I want to generate a synthetic dataset, in python, composed of 10 features. 5 are dependent among each others and 5 are independent.

## Generate dependent features.

`dependent_features = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(dimensions,))`

## Generate independent features.

`independent_features = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(dimensions-dependent_features,))`

## Generate data.

`distribuation = np.concatenate((dependent_features, independent_features), axis=1)`

I don't know how to generate the dependent features.

Comment: I think your question ist not specific enough or is lacking details. What kind of dependencies are you looking for?

Comment: Hello, any kind of dependency. In fact, i will use this synthetic data set to test a dependency estimator.

Comment: Well in that case I would suggest to put some more thought into the type of dependencies you want to simulate and how you model them. In the current form, the question is much to brought.
I can directly imagine a dozend different ways to generate variables that are *somehow* dependend.

Comment: Another question: do you need uniformly distributed features?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

n_samples = 1000

# Independent 
independent_features = np.random.rand(n_samples, 5)

# Dependent (use noise create 4 dependent on the first)
base = np.random.rand(n_samples, 1)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(n_samples, 4))  
dependent_features = np.hstack((base, base + noise))

# Stack them
dataset = np.hstack((independent_features, dependent_features))
```

You can alternatively use scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

n_samples = 1000

# Independent
X_independent, _ = make_regression(
  n_samples=n_samples, n_features=5, n_informative=5, noise=0.1
)

# Dependent
X_dependent, _ = make_regression(
  n_samples=n_samples, n_features=5, n_informative=1, noise=0.1
)

# Stack them
X = np.hstack((X_independent, X_dependent))

# Step not needed but can help depending on the model you use
X = shuffle(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Being able to generate the type of data you want without relying on a specific package is a useful skill for a lot of reasons.

From first principles, 2 variables, A & B, are independent if the following relation holds true: P(A=a | B=b) = P(A=a)*P(B=b). If they are not independent, P(A=a | B=b) **!=** P(A=a)*P(B=b).

Numerically, independent variables have low covariance while dependent variables will have high covariance. (Note: we're only considering the association between continuous variables here).

I work primarily in R, but the logic remains the same. I'll supply 2 toy examples that you can extend to any number of variables from any number of distributions.

```
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ #
# Simulating dependence among variables
# +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ #
# 

# Let X = Son Height, Y = Father Height
#     
#   X,Y ~ Normal(mu, var)
# 
# Let Father Height have a mean of 70" with an sd of 4"
# Let Son Height depend on Father height in the following manner: 
#   if Father < mean(Father) => Prob(Son > Father) = 0.75
#   if Father > mean(Father) => Prob(Son > Father) = 0.25
#   
#   
#   Create a generating mechanism based on the father's height
#     if(F > mu.F)
#       do
#         S <- rnorm(1, 74, 4) with probability .25 
#       else 
#         S <- rnorm(1, 65, 4) with probability .75
#     
#     if(F < mu.F)
#       do  
#         S <- rnorm(1,74,4) with probability .75
#       else
#         S <- rnorm(1,65,4) with probability .25 
#       

# Take a random sample of 100 fathers

n    <- 100
mu.F <- 70
sd.F <- 4

set.seed(42) # R v.4.3.0
fathers <- rnorm(n, mu.F, sd.F)

sons <- 
  sapply(fathers, \(f){   # for every dad
  taller = rnorm(1,75,4)  # sample a taller son
  shorter = rnorm(1,65,4) # and a shorter son
  
  if(f > mu.F){
    # if dad's taller than average
    # son is from the taller distribution with prob 0.25          
    sample(c(taller, shorter), 1, prob = c(0.25,0.75)) 
    }
  else{
    # if dad's shorter than average 
    # son is from the taller distribution with prob 0.75
    sample(c(taller, shorter), 1, prob = c(0.75, 0.25))
    }
  
})

cor(fathers,sons) ## works out to correlation of -0.4606312

# To extend this to more than 2 variables, you just need to define
# the relationships between the levels of variable i and variable j

# Since you're using random uniform variables, we can do the following:

set.seed(42)
x1 <- runif(100)

x2 <- sapply(1:100, \(i){
  ## high (-) dependence on x1
  if(x1[i] <= (1/3)){ # if x1[i] low, x2[i] is high and vice-versa
    min = 0.75
    max = 1.00
  }
  else{
    min = 0.00
    max = 0.25
  }
  runif(1, min = min, max = max)
})

x3 <- sapply(1:100, \(i){
  ## high (+) dependence on x1
  if(x1[i] <= (1/3)){ # if x1[i] is low, x3[i] is low
    min = 0.00
    max = 0.10
  }
  else{
    min = 0.90
    max = 1.00
  }
  runif(1, min = min, max = max)
})

X = cbind(x1, x2, x3)
cor(X)

## Correlation Matrix for x1, x2, x3
|          |     x1    |    x2     |    x3    |
| -------- | --------- | --------- | -------- |
|  x1      | 1.0000000 | -0.8185895| 0.8220646|
|  x2      | -0.8185895|  1.0000000|-0.9786708|
|  x3      |  0.8220646| -0.9786708| 1.0000000|
```